# Derivative of $\nabla_{\theta} f(x, \theta) f(x, \theta)$ (the gradient of the function times the function itself)

Tags: nonlinear-regression, derivative, gradient

I am having troubles computing the derivative of $\nabla_{\theta}f(x, \theta)f(x, \theta) $ (the gradient of the function $f(x, \theta)$ times the function itself) that is
\begin{align}
D(\nabla_{\theta}f(x, \theta)f(x, \theta)), 
\end{align}
for $\theta = (\theta_1, \theta_2)^T$ and where $Df = (\partial_{\theta_1}f(x, \theta), \partial_{\theta_2}f(x, \theta)) \in \mathbb{R}^{1\times2}$. The gradient is a column vector, $\nabla_{\theta}f(x, \theta) \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times1}$.

I get this to be equal to
\begin{align}
D^2f(x, \theta)f(x, \theta) + \nabla_{\theta}f(x, \theta)\nabla_{\theta}f(x, \theta)^T, 
\end{align}
where $D^2f(x, \theta)$ is the Hessian and $\nabla_{\theta}f(x, \theta)\nabla_{\theta}f(x, \theta)^T$ is the outer product of the gradients,
but my numerical calculations (using the numDeriv package in R) do not seem to match this.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: When you say $D^2f(x,\theta)f(x,\theta)$ is the Hessian, is that just a typo for $D^2f(x,\theta)$ is the Hessian?

Comment: @ThomasLumley yes, sorry for that.

Comment: First, remove the superfluous references to "$x$" because they complicate the problem.  Then, consider a simple function that is easy to differentiate several times, such as $f(\theta)=\theta_1^2+2\theta_1\theta_2 + 3\theta_2^2.$ It ought to be quick and easy to work out the answer--and that will point the way towards a general answer.

Comment: thanks @whuber!

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out myself. Thanks for the function recommendation, @whuber.

For the function $f(\theta) = \theta_1^2 + \theta_2^2 + \theta_1 \theta_2$,
the gradient of the function equals
\begin{align}
\nabla_{\theta}f(\theta)  = \left[\begin{matrix}2 \theta_{1} + \theta_{2}\\\theta_{1} + 2 \theta_{2}\end{matrix}\right], 
\end{align}
and the Hessian equals
\begin{align}
D^2f(\theta) = \left[\begin{matrix}2 & 1\\1 & 2\end{matrix}\right].
\end{align}

Now, the gradient of the function times itself equals

\begin{align}
\nabla_{\theta}f(\theta) f(\theta) = 
\left[\begin{matrix}\left(2 \theta_{1} + \theta_{2}\right) \left(\theta_{1}^{2} + \theta_{1} \theta_{2} + \theta_{2}^{2}\right)\\\left(\theta_{1} + 2 \theta_{2}\right) \left(\theta_{1}^{2} + \theta_{1} \theta_{2} + \theta_{2}^{2}\right)\end{matrix}\right]. 
\end{align}

The derivative of this quantity (the one I was interested in) equals

\begin{align}
D(\nabla_{\theta}f(\theta) f(\theta)) 
&= 
\left[\begin{matrix}2 \theta_{1}^{2} + 2 \theta_{1} \theta_{2} + 2 \theta_{2}^{2} + \left(2 \theta_{1} + \theta_{2}\right)^{2} & \theta_{1}^{2} + \theta_{1} \theta_{2} + \theta_{2}^{2} + \left(\theta_{1} + 2 \theta_{2}\right) \left(2 \theta_{1} + \theta_{2}\right)\\\theta_{1}^{2} + \theta_{1} \theta_{2} + \theta_{2}^{2} + \left(\theta_{1} + 2 \theta_{2}\right) \left(2 \theta_{1} + \theta_{2}\right) & 2 \theta_{1}^{2} + 2 \theta_{1} \theta_{2} + 2 \theta_{2}^{2} + \left(\theta_{1} + 2 \theta_{2}\right)^{2}\end{matrix}\right] \\ 
&= \left[\begin{matrix}2 & 1\\1 & 2\end{matrix}\right](\theta_1^2 + \theta_2^2 + \theta_1 \theta_2) + 
\left[\begin{matrix}2 \theta_{1} + \theta_{2}\\\theta_{1} + 2 \theta_{2}\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}2 \theta_{1} + \theta_{2}, \theta_{1} + 2 \theta_{2}\end{matrix}\right] \\ 
& = 
D^2f(\theta)f(\theta) + \nabla_{\theta}f(\theta) \nabla_{\theta}f(\theta)^T.
\end{align}

So the identity holds.

For a general function $f{\left(\theta_{1},\theta_{2} \right)}$, the gradient of this function times itself equals
\begin{align}
\left[\begin{matrix}f{\left(\theta_{1},\theta_{2} \right)} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_{1}} f{\left(\theta_{1},\theta_{2} \right)}\\f{\left(\theta_{1},\theta_{2} \right)} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_{2}} f{\left(\theta_{1},\theta_{2} \right)}\end{matrix}\right]
\end{align}

and the derivative of this equals
\begin{align}
\left[\begin{matrix}f{\left(\theta_{1},\theta_{2} \right)} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial \theta_{1}^{2}} f{\left(\theta_{1},\theta_{2} \right)} + \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_{1}} f{\left(\theta_{1},\theta_{2} \right)}\right)^{2} & f{\left(\theta_{1},\theta_{2} \right)} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial \theta_{2}\partial \theta_{1}} f{\left(\theta_{1},\theta_{2} \right)} + \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_{1}} f{\left(\theta_{1},\theta_{2} \right)} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_{2}} f{\left(\theta_{1},\theta_{2} \right)}\\f{\left(\theta_{1},\theta_{2} \right)} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial \theta_{2}\partial \theta_{1}} f{\left(\theta_{1},\theta_{2} \right)} + \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_{1}} f{\left(\theta_{1},\theta_{2} \right)} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_{2}} f{\left(\theta_{1},\theta_{2} \right)} & f{\left(\theta_{1},\theta_{2} \right)} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial \theta_{2}^{2}} f{\left(\theta_{1},\theta_{2} \right)} + \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_{2}} f{\left(\theta_{1},\theta_{2} \right)}\right)^{2}\end{matrix}\right]
\end{align}

which equals
\begin{align}
\left[\begin{matrix}\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial \theta_{1}^{2}} f{\left(\theta_{1},\theta_{2} \right)} & \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial \theta_{2}\partial \theta_{1}} f{\left(\theta_{1},\theta_{2} \right)}\\\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial \theta_{2}\partial \theta_{1}} f{\left(\theta_{1},\theta_{2} \right)} & \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial \theta_{2}^{2}} f{\left(\theta_{1},\theta_{2} \right)}\end{matrix}\right] f{\left(\theta_{1},\theta_{2} \right)}
+ 
\left[\begin{matrix}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_{1}} f{\left(\theta_{1},\theta_{2} \right)}\\\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_{2}} f{\left(\theta_{1},\theta_{2} \right)}\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_{1}} f{\left(\theta_{1},\theta_{2} \right)}, \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_{2}} f{\left(\theta_{1},\theta_{2} \right)}\end{matrix}\right] \\ 
=
D^2f{\left(\theta_{1},\theta_{2} \right)} + \nabla_{\theta}f{\left(\theta_{1},\theta_{2} \right)}f{\left(\theta_{1},\theta_{2} \right)}^T.
\end{align}

The reason for my confusion (I already did those derivations in my notebook) was a minor typo in my R code :)
I leave the derivations here for someone in the future who might run into the same problem as me.

The reason I was interested in $D(\nabla_{\theta}f{\left(\theta_{1},\theta_{2} \right)}f{\left(\theta_{1},\theta_{2} \right)})$ is when finding the Hessian of the loss function in non-linear least squares
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}(y - f{\left(\theta_{1},\theta_{2} \right)})^2. 
\end{align}